# Any reason behind the ending of Inglourious Basterds?

Tags: analysis, ending, inglourious-basterds

This is about the movie - [Inglourious Basterds](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0361748/)

> This movie takes the (possibly) actual failed attempt to assassinate Hitler in a movie theater (I'm not able to find any data for the real-life attempt) and flips the story around to a successful assassination.

Any particular reason this was done and that particular event from history was chosen?

Comment: Was there even a real historical assassination attempt involving a cinema? I thought the whole plot was completely made up and not just the ending. And of course it had to be the cinema, because well, *Tarantino* loves the cinema and it's his way for handling stuff.

Comment: I do remember reading about such an assassination attempt in a theater (may have been a play) much before the movie released. I'm trying to get a link to such an event in actual history right now, struggling to do so however :(

Comment: Well Lincoln was killed in theather, but I doubt that someone tried to kill Hitler in cinema - it's a question for historians... And Hitler died in the movie because everyone would think he wouldn't :)

Comment: I don't recall any such attempt in real life, but feel free to check [the relevant Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assassination_attempts_on_Adolf_Hitler). Also, the title of your question isn't exactly the same as the content.

Comment: Thanks for the link @BCdotWEB, the details of the assassinations are not there in that one, only the place and who attempted it.

Comment: The reason that it ends like that is that every Fairy Tale deserves a Fairy Tale ending.

Comment: In real life Hitler was never punched out by Captain America, either.  http://www.thecomicbooks.com/img/1941-captainamericacomics1.gif

Comment: There was never an assassination attempt on Hitler in a theater. Though much of the film loosely follows history, the movie itself is not meant to be historical or biographical. It's akin to believing that Abraham Lincoln was a vampire slayer. Or that William Wallace actually plooked Isabel of France (who was actually 4 years old when those events took place).

Comment: The questions also asked "..and that particular event from history..."  I have explained that the event never happened.  I suppose I could fill it in a little more with info on why the movie ended that way, if I can find some conical source.  This shouldn't have been converted to a comment, IMO.

Comment: @JohnnyBones It should, since the fact if this was a real historical assassination attempt or not has always been marginal to the actual question and not its core question asked. That being said, your new answer indeed *is* an actual answer and I'm glad I could motivate you to write it.

Comment: [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_assassination_attempts_on_Adolf_Hitler) is a list of 42 documented assassination attempts on Hitler.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer to your question is:

> Tarantino himself has remarked: "In this story, cinema changes the
>   world, and I fucking love that idea!"

The reality is; There was never an assassination attempt on Hitler in a theater. Though much of the film loosely follows history, the movie itself is not meant to be historical or biographical. Tarantino just thought the idea of a world-changing event happening in a theater sounded cool, so he moved the demise of Hitler to a cinema.

Comment: Thanks for that @Johnny Bones, I don't know why on earth I've been aware of a theater assassination attempt from before the movie was made ..